# Scrollable Matplotlib figure not working from function

Tags: python, function, matplotlib, jupyter, spyder

I am at the moment working on medical images and writing code for preparing a training set.
To do this, I need to scroll through slices of volume data.

My main IDE is Spyder, but the standard implementation of the IndexTracker object does not work for me WITHIN a function.

This standard implementation works for me:
https://matplotlib.org/gallery/animation/image_slices_viewer.html

But as soon as I put the creation of the plot into a function, the created plot is no longer scrollable:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class IndexTracker(object):
    def __init__(self, ax, X):
        self.ax = ax
        ax.set_title('use scroll wheel to navigate images')

        self.X = X
        rows, cols, self.slices = X.shape
        self.ind = self.slices//2

        self.im = ax.imshow(self.X[:, :, self.ind])
        self.update()

    def onscroll(self, event):
        print("%s %s" % (event.button, event.step))
        if event.button == 'up':
            self.ind = (self.ind + 1) % self.slices
        else:
            self.ind = (self.ind - 1) % self.slices
        self.update()

    def update(self):
        self.im.set_data(self.X[:, :, self.ind])
        self.ax.set_ylabel('slice %s' % self.ind)
        self.im.axes.figure.canvas.draw()

def plot(X):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
    tracker = IndexTracker(ax, X)
    fig.canvas.mpl_connect('scroll_event', tracker.onscroll)
    plt.show()

plot(np.random.rand(200, 200, 500))
```

What could be the problem? How do I create my scrollable plot from within a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem myself:
The issue is, that matplotlib does not correctly identify the plot instance and thus it must be set in the function.
A basic and NOT UNIVERSAL OR PRACTICAL application would be the following:

```
figList,axList=[],[]
def plotSlices(image, view):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
    figList.append(fig)
    axList.append(ax)
    axList[-1].set_title(view)
    tracker = IndexTracker(axList[-1], image)
    figList[-1].canvas.mpl_connect('scroll_event', tracker.onscroll)
    plt.show(figList[-1],block=False)
```

In which a numpy array is read together with the perspective of the image. This is used only for the title, so you can remove it/hardcode the title.
The fig and ax objects are appended to respective lists, from which only the last added elements are given to matplotlib to plot.

This way, scrolling through plots defined in the function works. 
One issue is that I'm apparently overloading the .show() method, which should only accept a block=False/True argument, but does actually correctly identify the correct plot like this: 
plt.show(fig,block=False)
It throws an error adressing this, but ultimately works. Perfect!

Answer (score 0):

### Short answer

In a cleaner way, you should keep access to the instance of the tracker in the main context. Otherwise, this tracker is destroyed at the ending of the function.

Following the official exemples https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/event_handling/image_slices_viewer.html?highlight=slice%20viewer that I have adapted to wrap the plot inside a function.

```
def ShowSlice():
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
    X = np.random.rand(20, 20, 40)
    tracker = IndexTracker(ax, X)
    fig.canvas.mpl_connect('scroll_event', tracker.on_scroll)
    plt.show()
    return tracker
    
# ShowSlice()  # Does not works    
tr = ShowSlice()  # Works
```

### My investigations

Thanks for your question, that was exactly my current problem. Your own answer help me a lot to find the real reason of this behavior.

The solution you present underlines a problem of knowing of certain variables linked at least to the figure or axis.

I have already meet a similar problem, with animation in matplotlib. And the solution for this problem was to keep an instance of the animation in the main context as illustrated in the following exemple :
https://matplotlib.org/2.1.2/gallery/animation/basic_example.html, even if the animation object (`line_ani` and `im_ani`) is not used, it is necessary to keep then in memory.

Here the problem seems to be exactly the same but with the tracker instance.

A deeper reading of the documentation of `mpl_connect` confirm that :
https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/event_handling.html#event-connections

> The FigureCanvasBase.mpl_connect method returns a connection id (an
> integer), which can be used to disconnect the callback via
>
> **Note**
>
> The canvas retains only weak references to instance methods used as
> callbacks. Therefore, you need to retain a reference to instances
> owning such methods. Otherwise the instance will be garbage-collected
> and the callback will vanish. This does not affect free functions used
> as callbacks.

Thanks for your reading.